# AngularFire 2 access value without knowing ID

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I'm trying to make a simple chat, just to practice, but i want to access the childs inside another child.
I writed the ID's by hand, but imagine that i dont know the ids, because firebase created ones randomly.

The thing is, that I can iterate the list, but I cant access the childs because I don't know the ID, and I only want to see the the msg in the view.

Firebase database structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGqZD.jpg

This is the code that I have:

```
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public af: AngularFire) {
    af.database.list('/chats/chatroom').subscribe(items => {
      console.log(items);
      items.forEach(snapshot => {
        console.log(snapshot);
        this.msg.push(snapshot.msg);
      })
    });
```

Thank you!!

Comment: To access the value of the snapshot, use `val()` so: `this.msg.push(snapshot.val().msg);`.

Comment: Hi! I tried that code, but it says that val is not a function.

Comment: Hmmm.... weird, the AngularFire documentation says that `.val()` should work: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/3-retrieving-data-as-lists.md#retrieving-the-snapshot

Comment: I also used the same code that the documentation has, and still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recreated your data structure, and seems like you miss the following option when you create the reference: `{ preserveSnapshot: true }`

The following creates your desired array:

```
af.database.list('/chats/chatroom').subscribe(items => {
  console.log(items);
  items.forEach(snapshot => {
    console.log(snapshot);
    this.msg.push(snapshot.val().msg);
  })
```

Please let me know if this help you :)

Comment: @Mystearica can you please mark the answer as solved - if it helped you?